# Mouse pointer blocked after control or shift buttons are pressed

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, blocking

I know that this issue is strange, but I thing it is interesting to share it and know if someone else has experimented this.

Depending on which usb port is used to plug the keyboard and the mouse (both have usb connector) the mouse pointer is blocked if I press control or shift buttons. To have the mouse working again I have to unplug the mouse and plug it again.

If I plug the mouse in the same usb port, the same happens if I press control or shift buttons, so I use to test all the possible combinations (changing also the usb port of the keyboard) until I find the correct combination (not always is the same).

I have tested several mouses and several keyboards, and with all of them the same happens. Moreover, if I plug my Wacom tablet, both mouse and keyboard stop working.

The operative systems I have tested are Windows10, Devian8, Ubuntu 17.04 and Ubuntu 17.10. Currently I am using Ubuntu 17.10.

In windows this is not happening such frequently, but it happens, so I think it could be something related with the hardware, but I have not clue of what could it be.

My hardware setup:

Main hardware

```
CPU: Intel Core i7-4770K
Power supply: Tacens Mars Gaming Vulcano 750W 80 Plus Silver
```

PCI Devices

```
Host bridge               : Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
PCI bridge                : Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
USB controller            : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Communication controller  : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
Ethernet controller       : Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 04)
USB controller            : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Audio device              : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
PCI bridge                : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge                : Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d4) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
PCI bridge                : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
USB controller            : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
ISA bridge                : Intel Corporation Z87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
SATA controller           : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
SMBus                     : Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
VGA compatible controller : NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 770] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Audio device              : NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
PCI bridge                : Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
SATA controller           : Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9172 SATA 6Gb/s Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
```

USB Devices

```
Intel Corp.
Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Intel Corp.
Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Hitachi, Ltd
Hitachi, Ltd
Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Razer USA, Ltd RZ01-020300 Optical Mouse (Diamondback)
Fujitsu, Ltd
Hitachi, Ltd
Megawin Technology Co., Ltd
Hitachi, Ltd
Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Some more info about your hardware would be useful.

Comment: I have included the elements I think that could be interesting, but I can add more info if you think it could help. Thanks.